# Fitting one crate into another crate diagonally

Tags: geometry

The two crates have not been built yet. We need to determine if the smaller one will fit in the larger one. The large crate will be 87" long x 47' wide. The internal crate will be too long to fit end to end. The only way it may fit is if it is loaded diagonally.The second crate will be 94" long by 6" wide. Height will not be an issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean $47$ inches wide, not $47$ feet as written?  With feet it is easy.

Comment: Yes, 47". Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

To fit a rectangle with short side 6 in a rectangle 47 by 87, split the 47 side into 5.381 + 41.619 , then the 87 into 2.655 + 84.345. The resulting rectangle is only 94.054 I see, you need only 94.

Just fits.

The system is $x^2 + y^2 = 36,$ then $47x - x^2 = 87y - y^2.$ After which the long side is
$$ \sqrt {\left(47 - x \right)^2   + \left(87 - y \right)^2 \; \; }  $$

The length I am calling $x$ is the positive real root of
$$  4x^4 - 188x^3 + 9634x^2 + 3384x - 271188 $$
and is more accurately
$$ x \approx 5.380602262409443809336947831 $$
$$ y \approx 2.655017757709800098894024675  $$

$$ 47-x \approx 41.61939773759055619066305217 $$
$$ 87-y \approx 84.34498224229019990110597533 $$
$$ \sqrt {\left(47 - x \right)^2   + \left(87 - y \right)^2 \; \; } \approx  94.05450705570683636463861850   $$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The length of the diagonal of the large crate is $$\sqrt{87^2 + 47^2} = 98.9$$. This only allows 4.9 inches to accommodate the 6 inches width of the smaller crate, at both ends. It won't fit but it's very close. You need the diagonal to be no less than 5 inches longer to fit. If this is a real world situation and not just a math problem, I would add in another inch.

I rechecked my numbers. The right triangle at the corner has dimensions 2.852, 5.279 and 6. The dimension from the end of smaller box to the corner of larger box is 2.852*5.279/6 = 2.51. You have 4.9/2 = 2.45 available. Like I said, close.

Comment: MathJax hint:  to get multicharacter things under the square root sign, put them in braces, so \sqrt{a^2+b^2} gives $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

Comment: I concur with those saying it will fit. The smaller box when skewed into place (not lie along the larger box diagonal) just fits by .05.

Answer (score 0):

We have a large rectangle with side lengths $a>b$ and a small rectangle with side lengths $c>d$, whereby $c>a>b>d$. The question is whether there is an angle $\theta\in\bigl]0,{\pi\over2}\bigr[\>$ such that
$$c\sin\theta+d\cos \theta\leq b\quad\wedge\quad d\sin\theta+c\cos\theta\leq a\ .\tag{1}$$
Let $\tan{\theta\over2}=:t\in\>]0,1[\>$. Then $(1)$ translates into
$$f(t):=(b+d)t^2-2ct+b-d\geq0\quad\wedge\quad g(t):=(a+c)t^2-2dt+a-c\geq0\ .\tag{2}$$
The zeros of $f$ are
$${c\pm\sqrt{c^2+d^2-b^2}\over b+d}\ .$$
The smaller of these is $>0$, and the larger $>1$. The zeros of $g$ are
$${d\pm\sqrt{d^2+c^2-a^2}\over a+c}\ .$$
The smaller of these is $<0$. It follows that there is an admissible $t$ satisfying $(2)$ **iff**
$${c-\sqrt{c^2+d^2-b^2}\over b+d}\geq{d+\sqrt{d^2+c^2-a^2}\over a+c}\ .$$
Here the LHS evaluates to $0.23345$, and the RHS to $0.23258$. It follows that the small crate can be placed in the interior of the large crate.